# scala "console" command gives error "Missing scala-library.jar"

Tags: scala, sbt

Under sbt, if I give "console" to start a REPL shell, I get the following error.

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last scalaInstance' for the full output
[error] (scalaInstance) Missing scala-library.jar
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 7, 2019 12:45:07 PM

$ sbt scalaVersion
[info] Loading global plugins from C:..\plugins
[info] Loading settings for project test from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:xx\test\project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] scalaVersion
[info]  2.11.12

$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] sbtVersion
[info]  1.3.0
```

Comment: Which `sbt` version do you use?

Comment: Could you do a `sbt clean` `sbt reload` and `sbt update`?

Comment: @ElBaulP I did try that. After sbt update, when I try "console", I get the same Missing scala-library.jar error.

Comment: @Suma : I use 1.3.0.

Comment: Are you setting managedScalaInstance to false? https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Configuring-Scala.html

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`assemblyOption in set: = (assemblyOption in set) .value.copy (includeScala = true)`

Source: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

if this doesn't solve the issue, it could be a compatibility issue with a plugin which you might have installed, it means that you would have to delete the plugin directory in %HOME%. and %HOME%.ivy2 because it caches some artifacts locally.

If you are not able to find the plugin try deleting %HOME%.ivy2 and running the console again, as it will remove the cached artifacts.

You might want to refer 
https://pt.coredump.biz/questions/50313823/why-does-running-tests-through-jenkins-user-on-build-slave-fail-with-missing-scalalibraryjar

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat unrelated but I ran into this error on one of my projects and deleting all caches (.m2, .ivy2, coursier) was not enough to fix this. I also had to clear out my .sbt folder (I assume emptying the boot directory). Be sure to backup any settings you still might need.

Answer (score 0):

can you try updating scala version in your sbt build? 
for example,

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.0"
```